# To avoid URL manipulation on Credit Card payment page

Tags: url, spring-security, payment, credit-card

My question is security related. We're using two payment gateways for our customers to pay. We are sending a payment link within our emails.

Here's example of link which is sent to client:

https://payment.somedomain.net.xxx/userid?amount=1,200.00&currency=USD&amount_editable=false&email=some@domain.com&description=InvXH10303%20for%20WordPress

Once is clicked you get to payment screen where you get this

http://screencast.com/t/Dj8nixnt5oH

This is how it looks on payment page. The URL string parameters are fully editable, which means that if you edit amount, email, user id or currency in URL string it reflects on that page.

Which lefts lot of things open.

How to avoid possibility of editing those information?

Any good advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The site you are using to process payments was poorly designed. It's hard to 100% protect your links from URL manipulation, but what I can suggest is that you switch over to a POST form instead of a GET form. It looks like the site has a SSL certificate, so that's at lesat good. Also, consider having some kind of server-side validation? Even just a 2 step validation would make it a lot harder to manipulate.

Comment: That is a deeply terrible design.  Ask the gateway if they have an alternate API. The way this should work is that you perform a server side post to them with the transaction details and then they return to you an obfuscated set of values to pass to the redirection page.

Comment: @AlexK. you mean similar technique how Paypal's pay button does it? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: I don't know how paypal works, a correct mechanic is to completely hide all that data from the end user by exchanging it in the background.

Comment: @AlexK. For example like this https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=dave%40x-team%2ecom&lc=BM&item_name=Test%20item&amount=10%2e00&currency_code=USD&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest

Try to click link, of course don't fill or pay, just take a look at the browser URL bar to see how it's encoded. There are some cases where POST can't be used.